# $\frac{d}{dx} \frac{1}{x+\frac{1}{x+\frac{1}{ \ddots}}}$, the derivative of an infinite continued fraction.

Tags: calculus, derivatives, fractions, continued-fractions

I computed the first few derivatives in the sequence $\frac{1}{x+\frac{1}{x}}, \frac{1}{x+\frac{1}{x+\frac{1}{x}}} \dots$ and eventually lost feeling in my fingers and also realized I was seeing nothing meaningful. Let

$$f(x,t) = \overbrace{\cfrac{1}{x+\cfrac{1}{x+\cfrac{1}{\ddots}}}}^{x\text{ appearing }t \text{ times.}}$$

**My question:** does there exist a closed-form of the derivative of an infinite continued fraction, at least for positive arguments? That is, does $g(x)$ such that:
$$g(x)=\lim_{t \to \infty}\frac{d}{dx}f(x,t)$$ 
Have a closed-form expression?

Comment: [Related.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3315633/104041)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $y:=\frac{1}{x+\frac{1}{x+\cdots}}=\frac{1}{x+y}$ so$$y^2+xy-1=0\implies y=\frac{-x\pm\sqrt{x^2+4}}{2}.$$If $x>0$, $y>0$ so$$y=\frac{-x+\sqrt{x^2+4}}{2}\implies\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{-1+\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+4}}}{2}.$$Your $f(x,\,t)$ are odd for each integer $t\ge0$, so if we are to extend this to $x\le0$ we need$$y=\frac{-x+\operatorname{sgn}x\cdot\sqrt{x^2+4}}{2},\,y^\prime=\frac{-1+\frac{|x|}{\sqrt{x^2+4}}}{2}.$$